# State is not getting changed after simulating click event

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create test cases for my application, providing source below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Tabs, Tab} from 'react-bootstrap';
import ManageUsers from './ManageUsers.jsx';
import ManageRoles from './ManageRoles.jsx';
import ManageUserGroups from './ManageUserGroups.jsx';

export default class UserManagement extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 1
    }
 }
handleSelect(key){
    this.setState({
      selectedTab: key
    });
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div className="container listView">
        <Tabs activeKey={this.state.selectedTab} onSelect={this.handleSelect} className="customNavTabsHorizontal" id="navUserMgmt">
          <Tab eventKey={1} title={this.state.multiLangMsgs.MANAGE_USERS}>
            <ManageUsers isSelected={this.state.selectedTab === 1 ? true : false} ></ManageUsers>
          </Tab>
          <Tab eventKey={2} title={this.state.multiLangMsgs.MANAGE_ROLES_PERMISSIONS}>
            <ManageRoles isSelected={this.state.selectedTab === 2 ? true : false} ></ManageRoles>
          </Tab>
          <Tab eventKey={3} title={this.state.multiLangMsgs.MANAGE_USER_GROUPS}>
            <ManageUserGroups isSelected={this.state.selectedTab === 3 ? true : false}></ManageUserGroups>
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and the test case is like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import UserManagement from './UserManagement.jsx';

describe('<UserManagement />', () => {
  it('should handle selected tab state changes', () => {
    const userMgmt = shallow(<UserManagement />);
    const secondTab = userMgmt.find('Tab').at(0);
    secondTab.simulate('click');
    expect(userMgmt.state().selectedTab).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

When I run the `npm test` it always gets fail saying that expected is 2 but actual is 1. It seems it's not setting the state value. Can any one please help me out with this.

Comment: see https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1201

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `shallow` rendering, it renders only elements exactly from one render function you test. It doesn't know how to handle click on `Tab`.

To simultate your case, you have 2 option:

1. Render also children nodes using `mount` rendering, and simulate click on DOM node.
2. Call `onSelect` or simultate `select` on `Tabs` element.